# Creating a custom and reliable task scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, memory, .net-core, scheduler

I'm trying to create my own C# task scheduler, so for example I want to run a specific void with an Id argument every Monday of the week. I also want to keep a list of all running tasks per scheduler.

So you would have a scheduler that contains a list of tasks and those tasks have actions and triggers, actions being the method(s) that I want to execute and triggers being for example every Monday of every week.

Now when the task is done and it has reached it's end date it has to pretty much dispose itself like it never existed. This is where I don't know what to do anymore.

Now this is an extreme example but I tried scheduling one million tasks that would run after 10 seconds. All the tasks ran but somehow were not disposed correctly. Visual Studio said that the Process Memory was about 700 MB and the Heap Memory about 2 MB after the tasks have disposed themselves.

I tried two things:

- A flush system that runs every 30 seconds and buffers finished tasks and removes them from the list and then from the buffer. This worked kinda, after running one million tasks it would give me a "Collection was modified" exception.
- Self disposing tasks, when the task is finished it will dispose of itself. When running this with one hundred thousand tasks it would dispose most of them and remove them from the list but I had at least five thousand tasks still in the task list.

My question is how do I correctly and reliably dispose the tasks and remove them from the task list so that they are no longer existing within the memory without getting any exceptions such as "Collection was modified".

Here is my code that I used, you might need to edit it a little to make it use the flush system and the self disposing system.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Timers;
using static TaskScheduler.Scheduler;

namespace TaskScheduler
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                scheduler.Schedule(Function, new Settings() { Id = i, Start = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10) });
            }

            scheduler.Schedule(Function, new Settings() { Id = 1123, Recurring = true, Start = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5), End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14) });

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(scheduler.Tasks.Count());

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        public static void Function(Task task)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Test function: {task._settings.Id}");
        }
    }

    public class Scheduler : IDisposable
    {
        public List<Task> Tasks = new List<Task>();
        public List<Task> FlushCollection = new List<Task>();

        private Timer timer; //Flush timer

        public Scheduler(TimeSpan time)
        {
            timer = new Timer(time.TotalMilliseconds);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Flush);

            timer.Start();
        }

        public void Flush(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
        {
            foreach (Task task in Tasks.ToArray())
            {
                if (task.timer == null)
                {
                    FlushCollection.Add(task);
                }

            }

            foreach(Task task in FlushCollection.ToArray())
            {
                Tasks.Remove(task);
            }

            FlushCollection.Clear();
        }

        public void Schedule(Action<Task> action, Settings settings)
        {
            Tasks.Add(new Task(this, action, settings));
        }

        public void Unschedule(Task task)
        {
            task.Dispose();

            Tasks.Remove(task);
        }

        public void Unschedule(int id)
        {
            Unschedule(Tasks.Where(x => x._settings.Id == id).FirstOrDefault());
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            foreach (Task task in Tasks.ToArray())
            {
                task.Dispose();
            }

            Tasks.Clear();
        }

        public class Task : IDisposable
        {
            public Scheduler _scheduler;

            public Action<Task> _action;
            public Settings _settings;

            public Timer timer;
            private DateTime next;

            public Task(Scheduler scheduler, Action<Task> action, Settings settings)
            {
                _scheduler = scheduler;

                _action = action;
                _settings = settings;

                Init();
            }

            public void Init()
            {
                next = DateTime.Now + _settings.Interval;

                timer = new Timer((_settings.Start - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
                timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Elapsed);

                timer.Start();

                if (_settings.Interval.TotalMilliseconds != 0)
                {
                    timer.Interval = _settings.Interval.TotalMilliseconds;
                }
            }

            public void Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
            {
                if (!Ready())
                {
                    return;
                }

                Run();
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                timer.Dispose();
                timer = null;
            }

            public bool Ready()
            {
                return DateTime.Now >= next;
            }

            public void Run()
            {
                _action(this);

                if (Expired() || !_settings.Recurring)
                {
                    _scheduler.Unschedule(this);
                }
            }

            public bool Expired()
            {
                if (DateTime.Now >= _settings.End)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

        public class Settings
        {

            public int? Id { get; set; }

            public bool Recurring { get; set; } = false;

            public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; } //Not required when not recurring.

            public DateTime Start { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
            public DateTime End { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.AddTicks(1);

        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this is just a prototype so it doesn't contain the whole trigger and action system yet and other things I mentioned.

Comment: This should be posted in `codereview.stackexchange.com`. If you want a reliable task scheduler, don't build your own. Use the OS's task scheduler, eg Task Scheduler on Windows or cron on Linux. In ASP.NET Core you can use Hangfire. In other cases you can use Quartz.Net

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - no, codereview is about quality of code and practices, not about specific technical solutions.

Comment: Using a timer *inside* the task is a problem in itself. This can't scale as it generates a *lot* of timer objects. Only *one* timer is actually needed. Have a single timer run eg every 1 second or 1 minute, look for tasks that need running and execute them. If you store tasks using their time slot, finding the tasks to run will be very fast. Eg you could use a `Dictionary<DateTime,List<MyTask>>`. If the timer fires every second, the slot will be the DateTime a task needs to run rounded to the second. If it's every minute, it will be rounded to the minute

Comment: @bommelding in this case it's a better fit. The problem isn't technical, it's about the entire architecture.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos could it be an idea to run three timers, one for seconds one for minutes and one for hours? You would also have three different lists for those timers to iterate through. And then split tasks that run for example every 10 seconds into the timer that checks every second. Otherwise if I have 100 daily tasks it would have to check those by the second.

Comment: @Typically Quartz.NET and Hangfire are open source. You can check how they solve this.  There are a *lot* of things you can try, depending on what kind of schedules you expect, how and when do you expect to modify them.

Comment: Dispose is a bit of misnomer for some people. Disposing an object doesn't remove it from memory, it is just a pattern for removing unmanaged resources used directly or indirectly by an object efficiently. When you called dispose on your Task objects, you correctly dispose your timer so that it can release it's unmanaged resources. however that's all dispose does. You then remove it from the list so nothing references the task object, also correct. But still it will remain in memory until the GC removes it, which will be at some non-deterministic point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use Quartz.NET and or Hangfire as scheduler solution.

https://www.quartz-scheduler.net

https://www.hangfire.io

Comment: This is a very low quality answer

Comment: @Saruman how would I make it better then? This is exactly what solved my problem and answered my question.

Comment: Your problem was "I'm trying to create my own C# task scheduler", not "Recommend me a working scheduler pls". Given this change of direction, this answer doesn't apply to the question asked. It also most-likely qualifies as a link-only answer. All in all, you are risking being viewed as a time waster. I imagine that more than one person took the time to read and understand your code (I did). Do a bit of research before opening spurious questions please.